# Permissions required to sync SP Calendar with Outlook

Tags: 2007, permissions, calendar, outlook, people-picker

I would like to create a Calendar in SharePoint (I think is SP 2007) for my team where I can see the member workloads by specifying in the "**People Selector**" field the name of the person.

The problem is that in my current company we have limited access rights to manage SharePoint, therefore every time I try to synchronise Outlook with our Team Site it fails.

What kind of permission would I require to grant me the ability to synchronise Outlook?

Would there be another solution?

Comment: It would be useful if you could add the error message you are getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have **Use Client Integration Features** permission enabled. [By default](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288074.aspx) this is enabled for everybody, but your SharePoint permissions were probably customized and this was disabled.

To change this, contact you administrator and ask him to [customize permission levels](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/manage-permission-levels-HA010117209.aspx) for your group(s).